react-google-recaptcha-v3: Handle reCAPTCHA response after 1 million requests
I am using react-google-recaptcha-v3 to get reCAPTCHA token to send accompanied with api.
const { executeRecaptcha } = this.props.googleReCaptchaProps;

        if (!executeRecaptcha)
        {
            console.log('Recaptcha has not been loaded');
            return;
        }

        const token = await executeRecaptcha(action);
        return token

I need to send an information to backend if reach 1 million requests. How to handle the error 429 when reaching 1 million requests? (from here
